# How to add additional Value in MySQL DB

Tags: mysql, sql-update, multiple-value

How can I add one value to the field in my table?

I update the field by below mysql, but it just update the value.

```
UPDATE table SET value= 3 WHERE id= 1
```

So here is my actual want to do:

Before I add value

```
+--------------+
| table        |
+--------------+
| id   | value |
+--------------+
| 1    | 1     |
+--------------+
| 2    | 2     |
+--------------+
```

After I add value

```
+-------------------+
| table             |
+-------------------+
| id   | value      |
+-------------------+
| 1    | 1 , 3      |
+-------------------+
| 2    | 2          |
+-------------------+
```

Comment: What type is your value column?

Comment: you can do this `UPDATE table SET value="1,3" WHERE id= 1` :)

Comment: You should never have multiple values in a database field.  This breaks the first normal form.  Read more about __database normalization__.

Answer (score 2):

It seems you are using an integer field for 'value' column, you can't store more than one number in one integer field, what you might do it's set both 'id' and 'value' columns as primary keys so you will be able to insert more than one value for the same id. If that's not what you want, consider using the 'SET' type.
For more info https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/set.html

Comment: The first suggestion, using a composite key, is the way to approach this.  You should have a row for each value to maintain normalization.

Answer (score 0):

I have a feeling it's not, but if that is literally what you want to happen...

```
UPDATE table SET value=CONCAT(value, ' , ', 3) WHERE id=1
```